# Theorem about winding number of two closed paths

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals, winding-number

> Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ closed paths and $w\in\mathbb{C}$ a point, so that $$\vert\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_1(t)\vert < \vert\gamma_1(t)-w\vert$$ on $[0,1]$. Prove that $$n(\gamma_1,w)=n(\gamma_2,w)$$
>   **Hint:** Use the path $\gamma(t)=\frac{\gamma_2(t)-a}{\gamma_1(t)-a}+a$.

I found some help with homotopy but we actually didn't learned something about this topic. We only get the definition of winding numbers $$n(\Gamma, z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta-z_0}$$

My first idea was, that I use this definition with $\gamma_2$ and solve the integral to get the line integral for $\gamma_1$. Unfortunately I don't know how to use the inequality given in the task. Any hints? Thank you very much!

Comment: Which inequality do you have in mind?

Comment: This one: $$\vert\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_1(t)\vert < \vert\gamma_1(t)-w\vert$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704076/showing-equality-of-winding-numbers?rq=1

Comment: See Prop. 3.3 page 38 here http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/214/214S3_0708.pdf

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! Don't want to create a duplicate. However a last question @Bacon: In this document they say that: $2\pi in(\gamma_2, w)=\varphi_2(b)-\varphi_2(a)$. Why one can say the winding number can be calculated with this function?

Comment: @jacmeird If you let let $\varphi: [a, b] \mapsto C$ be any path such that $\exp(\varphi(t)) = \gamma(t)−w$ for all $t \in [a, b]$. Then the function sending $t \in [a, b]$ to $(2πi)^{−1}(\varphi(t)−\tilde{\gamma}w(t))$ is a continuous integer-valued function on the interval $[a, b]$, and is constant on this interval (see Prop 1.17). It follows that $\varphi(b) − \varphi(a) = \tilde{\gamma}_w(b) − \tilde{\gamma}_w(a) = 2πin(\gamma, w)$.